# i'm connect multiple Database and i use Laravel Excel I can'n export. This is error "Database [mysql] not configured."

Tags: laravel

i'm connect multiple Database and i use Laravel Excel I can'n export. This is error "Database [mysql] not configured."

i'm use laravel 6.0 and phpmyadmin version 4.4.15.10

controller

```
    public function exportExcel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new merakiExport, 'MerakiBluetooth.xlsx');
    }
```

app/Exports

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\MerakiBluetoothTemp;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;


class merakiExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return MerakiBluetoothTemp::all();
    }
}
```

config/database

```
     'meraki' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST5', ''),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT5', ''),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE5', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME5', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD5', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET5', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

env

```
DB_HOST5=sql.laravel.com
DB_PORT5=3306
DB_DATABASE5=time_sheet
DB_USERNAME5=*****
DB_PASSWORD5=*****
```

Comment: did you specify the DB_CONNECTION in your env file ?
Otherwise Laravel will take the default connection specified in your config/database
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql').

Comment: Yes, i  specify the DB_CONNECTION in my env file

Comment: have you tried "php artisan config:clear" ?

Comment: I tried many times

Comment: i'm use query  DB::connection('meraki')->raw('MAX(create_at) as createTime ,count(*) AS total ')  But in exports I can't

Comment: since you are connected to several DB, did you specify 
**protected $connection = 'meraki';**
in your MerakiBluetoothTemp Model ?

Comment: `protected $connection = 'meraki';`  yes i  specify.

Comment: In case of multiple database, configure all databases in `.env` file and `database.php` file.

Comment: i'm thank you and I have succeeded with my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded too.

app/Exports

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\MerakiBluetoothTemp;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class merakiExport extends Controller implements FromCollection
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        return MerakiBluetoothTemp::all();
    }
}
```

Comment: so extending Controller fixed your problem ? I don't understand.